# How do I pass variables between activities in Android?

Tags: android

Assume I have a "post submission" feature on my application. There are two activities and layouts:

1. Main post activity
2. Location selection activity

How can I pass variables between them when they're already opened? I already know how when they haven't been opened. I use "singleTask" mode to prevent multiple instances.

Reason I need this is because there's a button that links to LocationSelectionActivity on the MainPostActivity. I want when someone clicked the button, select the location, then go back to the MainPostActivity without any activity restart so the filled fields will not reset.

Comment: you can just put your informations as extra inside the Intent you use to start the second activity

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Use `onActivityResult()` with `startActivityForResult()`.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)), you can override it in your Activity class and retrieve the new Intent in your `onResume` method.

```
    /**
     * Override super.onNewIntent() so that calls to getIntent() will return the
     * latest intent that was used to start this Activity rather than the first
     * intent.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent); // Propagate.
        setIntent(intent); // Passing the new intent to setIntent() means this new intent will be the one returned whenever getIntent() is called.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Activities for this, you are in your own "main process" so you should be using 1 Activity and 2 Fragments for this.

Then you can use `locationSelectionFragment.setTargetFragment(this);` in `MainPostFragment` before it is added to Activity's fragment transaction, this lets you use `getTargetFragment()` to just pass back the value:

```
((MainPostFragment)getTargetFragment()).giveValueBack(value);
```

But there are multiple other options each with their own strengths and weaknesses [as described in this article](https://proandroiddev.com/all-the-things-were-doing-wrong-but-take-for-granted-a-retrospective-glance-at-android-ad7e942d09cf).